# How to ad the Galleria slide show to my blogspot theme

Tags: jquery, html, css, galleria, blogspot

i downloaded the galleria zip file and everything but i have no idea what to do next. how do i make the slide show appear on my blog? do i need to download programs to do this or does anyone have the html that i can copy pasta into my blogspot?

Thanks

http://testingthisf.tumblr.com

i put in my photos but it comes up as just a bunch of hi res

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="galleria/galleria-1.2.5.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="gallery">
            <a href="http://tinypic.com?ref=332zfhf" target="_blank"><img src="http://i51.tinypic.com/332zfhf.jpg"</a>">
            <a href="http://tinypic.com?ref=b6pstt" target="_blank"><img src="http://i52.tinypic.com/b6pstt.jpg" border="0" alt="Image and video hosting by TinyPic"></a>
            "<a href="http://tinypic.com?ref=8y5ate" target="_blank"><img src="http://i51.tinypic.com/8y5ate.jpg" border="0" alt="Image and video hosting by TinyPic"></a>
            <a href="http://tinypic.com?ref=95rm7b" target="_blank"><img src="http://i53.tinypic.com/95rm7b.jpg" border="0" alt="Image and video hosting by TinyPic"></a>
            <a href="http://tinypic.com?ref=2ivk901" target="_blank"><img src="http://i52.tinypic.com/2ivk901.jpg" border="0" alt="Image and video hosting by TinyPic"></a>
            <a href="http://tinypic.com?ref=lhaoj" target="_blank"><img src="http://i56.tinypic.com/lhaoj.jpg" border="0" alt="Image and video hosting by TinyPic"></a>">
            <a href="http://tinypic.com?ref=v48ghz" target="_blank"><img src="http://i51.tinypic.com/v48ghz.jpg" border="0" alt="Image and video hosting by TinyPic"></a>
            <a href="http://tinypic.com?ref=mk8xub" target="_blank"><img src="http://i52.tinypic.com/mk8xub.jpg" border="0" alt="Image and video hosting by TinyPic"></a>
            <img src="<a href="http://tinypic.com?ref=25hfya0" target="_blank"><img src="http://i52.tinypic.com/25hfya0.jpg" border="0" alt="Image and video hosting by TinyPic"></a>
            <img src="<a href="http://tinypic.com?ref=2ccqb1w" target="_blank"><img src="http://i52.tinypic.com/2ccqb1w.jpg" border="0" alt="Image and video hosting by TinyPic"></a>
            <img src="<a href="http://tinypic.com?ref=2woybdg" target="_blank"><img src="http://i54.tinypic.com/2woybdg.jpg" border="0" alt="Image and video hosting by TinyPic"></a>
        </div>
        <script>
            Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
            $("#gallery").galleria({
                width: 500,
                height: 500
            });
        /script>
    </body>
</html>​​​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Galleria has many options and skins. I suggest going through their beginners guide.

http://galleria.aino.se/docs/1.2/getting_started/beginners_guide/

There are also some examples on the site, including the one at the bottom of that page which you should be able to just copy and paste.

Comment: i tried that but it didnt seem to work for me,i updated the question